# AndEngine supported devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I am starting to use AndEngine and trying to load a texture to make a sprite in a screen.
In my activity class I have

```
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

     DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

     CAMERA_WIDTH = dm.widthPixels;
     CAMERA_HEIGHT =  dm.heightPixels;

     float screenResolutionRatio = ((float)CAMERA_WIDTH/(float)CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    final EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true,
                                                    ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, 
                                                    new RatioResolutionPolicy(screenResolutionRatio),
                                                    this.mCamera);
        return options;
    }


public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback arg0)
            throws Exception {
      mTextures = new NTTextures(this);     

    }
```

NTTexture is a class where textures are loaded.

Here is the meaningfull part of the code:

```
public NTTextures(final BaseGameActivity activity) {
    try
    {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
          this.spritesheetTexturePack = new TexturePackLoader(activity.getAssets(), activity.getTextureManager()).loadFromAsset("gfx/baseAtlas.xml", "gfx/");
        this.mSpritesheetTexture = spritesheetTexturePack.getTexture();
        this.mSpritesheetTexturePackTextureRegionLibrary = spritesheetTexturePack.getTexturePackTextureRegionLibrary();
        this.ping= this.mSpritesheetTexturePackTextureRegionLibrary.get(baseAtlas.PING_ID);

       activity.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mSpritesheetTexture);


    } catch (final TexturePackParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(e));
        }

      }
```

So, then all this done, I have an error log like and a crash.

```
07-25 18:44:23.880: D/AndEngine(32659): NTGameActivity.onCreate @(Thread: 'main')
07-25 18:44:23.930: W/dalvikvm(32659): VFY: unable to resolve static method 391: Landroid/opengl/GLES20;.glVertexAttribPointer (IIIZII)V
07-25 18:44:24.100: D/AndEngine(32659): NTGameActivity.onResume @(Thread: 'main')
07-25 18:44:24.290: D/AndEngine(32659): VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0 1309647
07-25 18:44:24.290: D/AndEngine(32659): RENDERER: Adreno 200
07-25 18:44:24.290: D/AndEngine(32659): EGLCONFIG: EGLConfig(Red=5, Green=6, Blue=5, Alpha=0, Depth=0, Stencil=0)
07-25 18:44:24.290: D/AndEngine(32659): EXTENSIONS: GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_NV_fence GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_QCOM_memory_monitor 
07-25 18:44:24.290: D/AndEngine(32659): MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS: 16
07-25 18:44:24.290: D/AndEngine(32659): MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 251
07-25 18:44:24.290: D/AndEngine(32659): MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 222
07-25 18:44:24.300: D/AndEngine(32659): MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 16
07-25 18:44:24.300: D/AndEngine(32659): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
07-25 18:44:24.300: D/AndEngine(32659): NTGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated @(Thread: 'GLThread 9')
07-25 18:44:24.300: D/AndEngine(32659): NTGameActivity.onCreateGame @(Thread: 'GLThread 9')
07-25 18:44:24.310: D/AndEngine(32659): NTGameActivity.onCreateResources @(Thread: 'GLThread 9')
07-25 18:44:30.310: I/global(32659): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
07-25 18:44:30.420: D/AndEngine(32659): NTGameActivity.onSurfaceChanged(Width=320,  Height=480) @(Thread: 'GLThread 9')
07-25 18:44:31.000: W/dalvikvm(32659): VFY: unable to resolve static method 353: Landroid/opengl/GLES20;.glDrawElements (IIII)V
07-25 18:44:31.000: W/dalvikvm(32659): VFY: unable to resolve static method 391: Landroid/opengl/GLES20;.glVertexAttribPointer (IIIZII)V
07-25 18:44:31.030: W/dalvikvm(32659): Exception Lorg/andengine/util/exception/AndEngineRuntimeException; thrown during Lorg/andengine/opengl/GLES20Fix;.<clinit>
```

I use for tests LG Optimus One with Android 2.2, so I supposed that my device has no needed GLES lib. Is that the reason of the errors or I have bugs in my code? Also, are there any list of supported devices for AndEngine?

**Addition:**
I checked tested phone specs - it has Adreno 200 with OpenGLES 2.0 support. So, it must have needed libs, but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method: `AndEngine.isDeviceSupported()`

Answer (score 4):

To make sure that deployment fails because of the wrong OpenGL version on your device you can insert the following line inside your Manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
```

Eclipse won't let you deploy your application on a device that doesn't support OpenGL ES 2.0. Also this will prevent users with older devices from downloading your application from Google Play. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've run the app on another phone - worked perfectly. So, it's about unacceptable device, and <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" /> didn't helped to forbid running om my device.